# C# Templated return type without templated class

Tags: c#, templates, interface

I am writing an API client:

ApiRequest.cs:

```
public abstract class ApiRequest<T> : IApiRequest<T>
{
   #region Data Members

   private readonly Type _returnType;

   #endregion

   #region Properties

   public Type ReturnType
   {
      get
      {
         return _returnType;
      }
   }

   #endregion

   #region Constructor

   public ApiRequest()
   {
      _returnType = typeof( T );
   }

   #endregion

   public abstract HttpRequestMessage Build();

}
```

ApiResponse.cs:

```
public struct ApiResponse<T> : IApiResponse<T>
{

   #region Data Members 

   private readonly ApiRequest<T> _request;
   private readonly T _response;

   #endregion

   #region Properties

   public ApiRequest<T> Request
   {
      get
      {
         return _request;
      }
   }

   public T Content
   {
      get
      {
         return _response;
      }
   }

   #endregion

   public ApiResponse( ApiRequest<T> request, T response )
   {
      _request = request;
      _response = response;
   }

}
```

Given how the request and response classes are laid out, I would like the client to be completely generic and have a function that returns type `T` of the request and response. I am currently trying:

```
public interface IApiClient
{
   IApiResponse<T> Request<IApiRequest<T>>( IApiRequest<T> request );
}
```

However, I am not allowed to use T in the method signature because `IApiClient` is not templated with it. How can I get around this so that my `ApiClient` does not have to specify a return type?

Comment: You could simply change the signature of your Request method to: IApiResponse<IApiRequest<T>> Request<T>(IApiRequest<T> request);
This way the type itself doesn't have any generic types attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need something like that

```
public interface IApiClient
{
    IApiResponse<T> Request<T>(IApiRequest<T> request);
}
```